# PHP Class 'DOMDocument' not found but all dependencies installed?

Tags: php, dom

Something is awry with my server's configuration, but I'm at a loss trying to solve this, so I'm reaching out to you PHP gurus.

Server details:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)
PHP 5.5.22
```

The following PHP packages are installed:

```
php-pdo-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-tcpdf-6.2.4-1.el7.noarch
php-mysql-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-tidy-5.4.16-3.el7.x86_64
php-process-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-bcmath-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-mcrypt-5.4.16-3.el7.x86_64
php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-xml-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-gd-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-mbstring-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-cli-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-php-gettext-1.0.11-10.el7.noarch
php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.2.4-1.el7.noarch
phpMyAdmin-4.3.11.1-1.el7.noarch
php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch
php-devel-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
```

Based on what I've read, php-xml should contain this class, but I'm still getting "Class 'DOMDocument' not found".

When I run phpinfo(), I see these lines related to the dom dependencies:

```
'--enable-dom=shared' '--with-dom-xslt=/usr' '--with-dom-exslt=/usr'
```

What's weird is that there is no DOM section listed even though "--enable-dom" is there.  I also attempted to include the dom.so extension in my php.inf configuration:

```
extension=dom.so
```

But none of these have worked.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you're under some namespace? If so, you should use your class as `\DOMDocument` (note the backslash at the beginning)

Comment: @Timofey Tried `$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');`, but it still throws the same error.

Comment: [according to the php.net](http://php.net/manual/dom.requirements.php) you need to install `libxml` and then run php with `--enable-libxml` parameter

Comment: @Timofey Both the `'--with-libxml-dir=/usr'` parameter is present, along with a section dedicated to `libxml` in my phpinfo output.

Comment: `$objDom = new \DOMDocument;` . It works to add the backslash if you use a namespace in your PHP class. I have tried it out.